# Python pandas: can I speed up this apply statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with ca. 250,000 rows x 6 columns. One of the columns is a date, formatted as text. I need to do 3 things:

1. Convert from text to date
2. Create a date where months and year are the same as the converted date, but the day is always the 15th
3. Calculate the date one month after the one calculated above

I do all of this with apply statements. They work, but seem slow to me: 7 seconds in total, whereas any SQL would take a fraction of a second, even without parallelisation, on the same machine. If this were a one-off I wouldn't invest time in speeding this up, but I must do it multiple times on multiple dataframes of similar size.

Is there any way I can speed up my code? Thanks a lot!

```
#this takes 3.1 seconds
df['date_reformatted'] = df['date_raw'].apply(lambda r: datetime.datetime.strptime(r, "%d/%m/%Y") )

# this takes 0.8 seconds
df['date_15']= df['date_reformatted'].apply(lambda r: datetime.date( r.year, r.month,15 ) ) 

# this takes 3.3 seconds
df['date_next_month']= df['date_15'].apply(lambda x: x + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1) )
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with the final date?  Convert it back to a string, or keep it in datetime form (or pd.Timestamp)?

Comment: My code below will provide significant time savings, but I need to know the format required for the final date (i.e. string vs. datetime).

Comment: I need to keep it in a date format. Might consider using numba. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just using integers and strings. Only convert to datetime objects if you really need them.

```
%%timeit -n10  df = pd.DataFrame({'date_raw': ['31/12/2000']*250000})
_, months, years = zip(*df.date_raw.str.split('/'))
months_years = [(1 if m == '12' else int(m) + 1, 
                 int(y) + 1 if m == '12' else int(y)) 
                for m, y in zip(months, years)]
# New dates in dd-mm-yyyy format:
df['new_date'] = ['15-{0}-{1}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in months_years]

10 loops, best of 3: 583 ms per loop

>>> df.tail()
          date_raw   new_date
249995  31/12/2000  15-1-2001
249996  31/12/2000  15-1-2001
249997  31/12/2000  15-1-2001
249998  31/12/2000  15-1-2001
249999  31/12/2000  15-1-2001
```

The new dates are in text form (which is why it was fast).  Creating datetime objects is a bit time consuming, but if you really need them:

```
%%timeit
df['new_date'].apply(lambda r: datetime.datetime.strptime(r, "%d-%m-%Y") )

1 loops, best of 3: 2.72 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do

```
df['date_formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_raw'], format= "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The second bit is a bit strange and I can't see how to vectorize it but you could get both columns in a single loop by

```
pd.DataFrame([(datetime.date(d.year, d.month, 15), 
               datetime.date(d.year, d.month + 1, 15)) for d in df.date_formatted], 
               columns=['date_15', 'date_next_month'])
```

might be a bit faster.

---

Comment: Thanks! Can you think of any suggestions for the last two statements, too (especially the last one) ?

Comment: See the edit. I can't see how to vectorize the middle part. You can probably add a month timedelta in pandas but I haven't figured it out. If you could then part 3 would easily follow part 4. A totally different approach would be to use regex on the original string form of the date

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated. The data comes from a Microsoft SQL Server. I have a feeling I should learn LINQ and how to apply it to SQL - it might make these things much faster

Comment: Yeah to get good performance in Pandas you have to vectorize and somethings that are unusual or awkward can't be done like that and so you have to use Python loops which are slow. In SQL the loops are fast soyou can do operations element-wise and still get good performance

Comment: Numba with nopython=true can help speed up loops which cannot be vectorised, too, but it has its limitations

Answer (score 2):

```
In [51]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date_raw': pd.to_datetime(['2000-12-31']*250000)}) 

In [66]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'date_raw': pd.to_datetime(['2000-12-31']*250000)})
10 loops, best of 3: 47.4 ms per loop

In [52]: df       
Out[52]: 
         date_raw
0      2000-12-31
1      2000-12-31
2      2000-12-31
3      2000-12-31
4      2000-12-31
5      2000-12-31
...           ...
249994 2000-12-31
249995 2000-12-31
249996 2000-12-31
249997 2000-12-31
249998 2000-12-31
249999 2000-12-31

[250000 rows x 1 columns]

In [53]: df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date_raw).to_period('M').to_timestamp('D') + pd.Timedelta('14d')

In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
         date_raw       date
0      2000-12-31 2000-12-15
1      2000-12-31 2000-12-15
2      2000-12-31 2000-12-15
3      2000-12-31 2000-12-15
4      2000-12-31 2000-12-15
5      2000-12-31 2000-12-15
...           ...        ...
249994 2000-12-31 2000-12-15
249995 2000-12-31 2000-12-15
249996 2000-12-31 2000-12-15
249997 2000-12-31 2000-12-15
249998 2000-12-31 2000-12-15
249999 2000-12-31 2000-12-15

[250000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Timings

```
In [55]: %timeit pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date_raw).to_period('M').to_timestamp('D') + pd.Timedelta('14d')
10 loops, best of 3: 62.1 ms per loop
```

This will be a little more compact after this [PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7832) is merged. IOW,
`pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date_raw).to_period('M').to_timestamp('15D')`

Your question 3 is easy if you again convert to periods, then adding 1 adds to of the same freq, month in this case. This is also vectorized.

```
In [80]: df['date_plus_1'] = (pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).to_period('M') + 1).to_timestamp('D') + pd.Timedelta('14d')

In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
         date_raw       date date_plus_1
0      2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
1      2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
2      2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
3      2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
4      2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
5      2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
...           ...        ...         ...
249994 2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
249995 2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
249996 2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
249997 2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
249998 2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15
249999 2000-12-31 2000-12-15  2001-01-15

[250000 rows x 3 columns]

In [82]: %timeit (pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).to_period('M') + 1).to_timestamp('D') + pd.Timedelta('14d')
10 loops, best of 3: 56.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the times...  `months = [np.random.randint(1, 13) for _ in range(250000)]`
`days = [np.random.randint(1, 29) for _ in range(250000)]`
`years = [np.random.randint(1950, 2015) for _ in range(250000)]` `dates = ['{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(d, m, y) for d, m, y in zip(days, months, years)]`
`%timeit pd.DataFrame({'date_raw': pd.to_datetime(dates)})
1 loops, best of 3: 17.2 s per loop`

Comment: very different results for mm-dd-yyyy vs. yyyy-mm-dd (%timeit pd.DataFrame({'date_raw': pd.to_datetime(['12-31-2015']*250000)})
1 loops, best of 3: 17.4 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'date_raw': pd.to_datetime(['2015-12-31']*250000)})
10 loops, best of 3: 40.6 ms per loop)

Comment: ``In [115]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d-%m-%Y')
1 loops, best of 3: 810 ms per loop``. You need to specify a formatting string if you are passing a non-ISO8601 date. However, OP indicated that the dates are coming from SQL, which by definition outputs in ISO8601.